# How to append coordinates from Bokeh Tap event to a python object?

Tags: python, bokeh

In the example below, I am trying to get the x and y coordinates that appear in the Div next to the plot when the bokeh plot is Tapped to be appended to the data dictionary coordList in their respective list.

```py
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Div
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.events import Tap

coordList = dict(x=[], y=[])

output_notebook()

def display_event(div, attributes=[], style = 'float:left;clear:left;font_size=10pt'):
    "Build a suitable CustomJS to display the current event in the div model."
    return CustomJS(args=dict(div=div), code="""
        var attrs = %s; var args = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
            args.push(Number(cb_obj[attrs[i]]).toFixed(2));
        }
        var line = "<span style=%r>(" + args.join(", ") + ")</span>\\n";
        var text = div.text.concat(line);
        var lines = text.split("\\n")
        if (lines.length > 35)
            lines.shift();
        div.text = lines.join("\\n");
    """ % (attributes, style))

x = np.random.random(size=4000) * 100
y = np.random.random(size=4000) * 100
radii = np.random.random(size=4000) * 1.5
colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" % (int(r), int(g), 150) for r, g in zip(50+2*x, 30+2*y)]

p = figure(tools="pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,reset")
p.scatter(x, y, radius=np.random.random(size=4000) * 1.5,
          fill_color=colors, fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)

div = Div(width=400, height=p.plot_height)
layout = row(p, div)

point_attributes = ['x', 'y']

p.js_on_event(Tap, display_event(div, attributes=point_attributes))

show(layout)
```

I'm not sure how the coordinates are saved and how to access them and append them to the lists.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to append to coordinates to a python object with code like above, because that code is generating standalone output (i.e. it is using "show"). Standalone output is pure static HTML and Bokeh JSON that is sent to browser, without any sort of connection to any Python process. If you want to connect Bokeh visualizations to a real running Python process, [that is what the Bokeh server is for](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html).

If you run a Bokeh server application, then you can use `on_event` with a real python callback to run whatever python code you want with the Tap even values:

```
def callback(event):
    # use event['x'], event['y'], event['sx'], event['sy']

p.on_event(Tap, callback)
```

Comment: I've tried using a python callback as you describe, but I get the error message:
`
WARNING:bokeh.embed.util:
You are generating standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python
callbacks (i.e. with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work.
`
Is this because I'm trying to do this in colaboratory? Is there a way to run a Bokeh server there?

Comment: Are you passing a *function* to `show`? Bokeh server apps in the notebook have their own particular necessary way to be arranged. Assuming you are using the latest Bokeh, your code should look like this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb As for colab, I have no idea, you will just have to try. Supporting regular notebooks and Jupyter lab is already a difficult burden, the project does not have resources to support colab in any official way.

Comment: BTW the fact that you were in colab (an unusual situation) was important, and should have been included in the original question. (It may be the entire reason things don't work in this case) As well as the relevant versions. If you are using an older version of Bokeh you may need to refer to an older version of that example notebook, for instance, since the latest version of the example notebook may use newer features that your version of Bokeh does not have. Questions should *always* have version information listed.